# Is there a way to break out of a while loop before the original condition is made false?

Tags: java, while-loop

Is there a way to break out of a while loop before the original condition is made false?

for example if i have:

```
while (a==true) 
{ 
    doSomething() ; 
    if (d==false) get out of loop ;
    doSomething_that_i_don't_want_done_if_d_is_false_but_do_if_a_and_d_are_true() ;
}
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: I love that the question has the answer 5 words in...

How can I 'break' out of this loop?
:)

Comment: Also - instead of using while (a==true), you can just use while (a). And for the if, you can use if (!d).

Comment: Ask a self-answering question, and you'll get a self-questioning answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the [`break` statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

```
if (!d) break;
```

*Note that you don't need to compare with `true` or `false` in a boolean expression.*

Comment: @Matt: For that I'd rather rename the variable name into something more sensitive :)

Answer (score 6):

`break` is the command you're looking for.

And don't compare to boolean constants - it really just obscures your meaning.  Here's an alternate version:

```
while (a) 
{ 
    doSomething(); 
    if (!d)
        break;
    doSomething_that_i_don't_want_done_if_d_is_false_but_do_if_a_and_d_are_true();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if(d==false) break;
```

This is called an "unlabeled" break statement, and its purpose is to terminate `while`, `for`, and `do-while` loops.

[Reference here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

Comment: You shouldn't promote usage of `== false` (and `== true` and `!= false` and `!= true`).

Answer (score 3):

[**`break;`**](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the `break` statement.

```
while (a==true) 
{ 
    doSomething() ; 
    if (d==false) break;
    doSomething_that_i_don't_want_done_if_d_is_false_but_do_if_a_and_d_are_true() ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(a)
{
    doSomething();
    if(!d)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following
Note the inclusion of braces - its good programming practice

```
while (a==true) 
{ 
    doSomething() ; 
    if (d==false) { break ; }
    else { /* Do something else */ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ( doSomething() && doSomethingElse() );
```

change the return signature of your methods such that `d==doSomething()` and `a==doSomethingElse()`.  They must already have side-effects if your loop ever escapes.

If you need an initial test of so value as to whether or not to start the loop, you can toss an `if` on the front.